# How I can install a local egg with easy_install using ansible?

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible, egg

I have a couple of local egg packages (company specific stuff) that I need to install as part of ansible provision.

I can do a hacky install using shell commands, but I'm wondering if there's a more ansible-friendly/saner way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not for eggs AFAIK. Ansible does have an `easy_install` module, but it doesn't haven an option to setup and egg locally.

You can try the `pip` module, but as you probably may have seen, local egg installs are not supported by `pip`.  So if you want to use the `pip` Ansible module you will have create a source distribution for those packages that you have as eggs.

You can see the documentation for the Ansible `pip` module here:

http://docs.ansible.com/pip_module.html

Also, the `pip` documentation is here:

http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/

Of course, you can hack the `easy_install` module for Ansible but that may take you longer than just using the Ansible `shell` module.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is an easy_install module, but it was problematic.

Not only did it not error out, it also refused to install within a VM.

I ended up using a shell command for each package with a with.

Comment: Sounds good, I didn't realize that. The easy_install module doesn't have a local eggs installation nevertheless. I have updated the answer as well.